# Validate object item in Yup

Tags: reactjs, validation, yup

I'm trying to validate form inputs, for example the user's first name:

```
const validateForm = () => {
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  "user.first_name": Yup.string().required("Enter name!"),
```

I tried all kinds of ways...currently my input looks like this

```
  <Input
          label={"Name"}
          value={updatedTenantData.user.first_name}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          name="user.first_name"
          error={errors["user.first_name"]}
        />
```

yet it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how should I name my input in Yup?

I can't just name it like first_name because value won't be sent as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Yup for validation, you should name the input field in Yup based on the nested structure of your form data. In your case, the input field is named "user.first_name," so you need to adjust the validation accordingly.

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const validateForm = () => {
  const validationSchema = Yup.object() shape({
    user: Yup.object().shape({
      first_name: Yup.string().required('Enter name!'),
    }),
  });
};
```